# Adding a conditional character to a print statement in C

Tags: c

I'm looking to break up binary into blocks or 8 digits. Is there a way to do the following in C without doing a second print line?

```
printf("%d%c", number>>(i-1) & 1, (i%8==0) ? ' ' : '');
```

Or is it not possible to do the "empty char" and I should add a second line to check for that?

Comment: You would probably loop outputting with `putchar` and on every 8th iteration add a space. You may find [Convert hex to binary from command line arguments C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500171/convert-hex-to-binary-from-command-line-arguments-c/35516912?r=SearchResults&s=2|19.1624#35516912) helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as an empty char. You can use `%s` with strings.

```
printf("%d%s", number>>(i-1) & 1, (i%8==0) ? " " : "");
```

Comment: Or `printf(i%8 ? "%d" : "%d ", number>>i-1 & 1)` and save `printf` the work of processing another specifier.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I pay printf good wages, I expect it to work for them.

Answer (score 0):

Put the condition before the printf for a quick fix, although its probably not the best way to do this:

```
(i%8==0) ? printf("%d ", number>>(i-1) & 1) : printf("%d", number>>(i-1) & 1);
```