# How I can divide my output (binary #) into two groups separated by a single space in C (Without Arrays)

Tags: c, printf, binaryformatter

I'm having difficulty formatting my output binary number in C Language. I'm trying to divide the output number into two groups of 8 digits, which would be separated by a single space.

this is my printf:

```
printf("%016ld in Binary\n", decNumtoBin);
```

This is my the output 0000001000101011

I wanted to look like this 00000010 00101011

Comment: Use division to get the first group and the modulus operator to get the second group. Then, print those two numbers with a space between them.

Comment: printf("%08ld %08ld in Binary\n", decNumtoBin/100000000, decNumtoBin%100000000);

Comment: Another option is simply to convert the value to its binary representation in a string and insert the separator of your choice (a `' '` space) every 8 characters padded to a total width of 16 bits.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BorisLipschitz it worked!

Comment: Thanks for your comment @DavidC.Rankin do you mean in printf?

Comment: Similar to [Convert hex to binary from command line arguments C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500171/convert-hex-to-binary-from-command-line-arguments-c/35516912?r=SearchResults&s=2|19.1024#35516912). Just another option for output with many fewer divisions and modulo. (and it will handle full 64-bit values without an issue)

Comment: Thank you @DavidC.Rankin for your help. Now I get it..

Comment: @BorisLipschitz please, post your answer in the answer section so I can mark my question as being answered. Thank you!

Comment: Sure thing, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting as 'answer', as requested in comments. In order to understand why it works, remember, you aren't actually printing a binary number, but a decimal one. And all you want to do is split it into 2 parts, which can be easily done using a simple division and a modulo.

```
printf("%08ld %08ld in Binary\n", decNumtoBin/100000000, decNumtoBin%100000000);
```